# Magento 2.3: Difference b/w Elastic search and Built-In search

Tags: magento2.3, elasticsearch

I've searched about difference between Elastic search and Built-In search option available in the Magento search configuration but didn't find an answer regarding the same.

I want to know the difference between these two options.

Thanks in advance for your better support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have worked with the Search and from my point of view:

**Built In Search:**

1. This is MYSQL Search
2. Here Data loads from Database that's why it is time consuming process.
3. It effects on site performance.

**Elastic Search:**

1. Basically it works with proxy server.
2. Here search request sends to proxy server and return response in the
   form of Json.
3. Site Performance Improves.

**Note:** Elastic search,which natively supports Lucene (a-search-engine-library ) can help you search existing data with the help of its REST_API or Query String.

Comment: There is also the MySQL search option available in the Magento search configuration with these two options. So the Built-in and MySQL search are same???

Comment: Difference was explained very well.Please provide more insights if possible.Thanks.

Comment: @sumit, Both search configuration depends on MySQL Search

Comment: Elastic search,which natively supports Lucene (a-search-engine-library ) can help you search existing data with the help of its REST_API or Query String.

Comment: OK, thank you for the information. You should add the last comment in your answer as it is also an important point.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: @Oscprofessionals, If I search an item for the first time, where it will get the item data?

Comment: It will create an entry in Search terms

Comment: @Oscprofessionals, which search pattern will run when the search term is created?